# real time audio processing in C++

Tags: c++, audio, latency

I want to produce software that reads raw audio from an external audio interface (Focusrite Scarlett 2i2) and processes it in C++ before returning it to the interface for playback. I currently run Windows 8 and was wondering how to do this with minimum latency?

I've spent a while looking into (boost) ASIO but the documentation seems fairly poor. I've also been considering OpenCL but I've been told it would most likely have higher latency. Ideally I'd like to be able to just access the Focusrite driver directly.

I'm sorry that this is such an open question but I've been having some trouble finding educational materiel on Audio Programming, other than just manipulating the audio when provided by a third party plug in design suite such as RackAFX. I'd also be grateful if anyone could recommend some reading on low level stuff like this.

Comment: also I realize that I'm unlikely to get the final product to an un-noticeably low latency, I'm just interested to see how close I can get.

Comment: You haven't said which platform you're using. On MacOSX it's possible to get the buffer latency down to less than 1ms for Firewire/Thunderbolt devices.  It'll be a bit more than this for USB.   5-10ms round-trip latency is achievable, although this comes at the expense of high CPU utilisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get very low latency by communicating directly with the Focuswrite ASIO driver (this is totally different than boost ASIO). To work with this you'll need to register and download the ASIO SDK from Steinberg. Within the API download there is a Visual C++ sample project called hostsample which is a good starting point and there is pretty good documentation about the buffering process that is used by ASIO.

ASIO uses double buffering. Your application is able to choose a buffer size within the limits of the driver. For each input channel and each output channel, 2 buffers of that size are created. While the driver is playing from and recording to one set of buffers your program is reading from and writing to the other set. If your program was performing a simple loopback then it would have access to the input 1 buffer period after it was recorded, would write directly to the output buffer which would be played out on the next period so there would be 2 buffer periods of latency. You'll need to experiment to find the smallest buffer size you can tolerate without glitches and this will give you the lowest latency. And of course the signal processing code will need to be optimized well enough to keep up. A 64 sample (1.3 ms @ 48kHz) is not unheard of.

Comment: MAC equivalent is Core audio driver

Comment: @UmNyobe: Sort of:  To achieve low latency on MacOSX one simply uses the normal higher level APIs of CoreAudio and AudioUnits  You can also use ASIO on MacOSX -  it simple sits on top of CoreAudio rather than using its own set of drivers - which it has traditionally done on Windows to avoid the system audio stack.  Reasons you'd want to do this are that is provides a cross-platform abstraction.